# Android - How to download a URL’s http contents which appear on scrolling down?

Tags: android, html, url, scroll

I have written an Android application to download HTTP contents of following URL: https://www.forbes.com/celebrities/list/

I want to use RegEx to extract image and name of the celebrities from HTML. But unfortunately, HTML content of celebrities list (`<tr></tr>` tags) only appears when user is “scrolling down”. In fact, my program doesn’t download any `<tr></tr>` tags inside `<tbody>` tag.

```
<tbody id="list-table-body">
</tbody>
```

How can I fix this problem?

**DownloadWebContent Class:**

```
public class DownloadWebContent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int read = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (read != -1) {
                char character = (char) read;
                output.append(character);
                read = inputStreamReader.read();
            }
            return output.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("HTML_Error", e.getMessage());
            return "Failed!";
        }
    }
}
```

**onCreate Method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);


    DownloadWebContent downloadWebContent = new DownloadWebContent();
    try {
        String htmlContent = downloadWebContent.execute("https://www.forbes.com/celebrities/list/").get();
        String htmlContentReplaced= htmlContent.replace("\"", "");
        textView.setText(htmlContentReplaced);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If they they dont have a API for this youre scraping their site without their consent, they will hunt you and sue you. Apart from that you have to call their source instead of the html scraping.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am writing this application just for practicing and I don’t want to publish it. However, I try using API for this purpose.